# Exporting a GeoTIFF with PyGRASS

Tags: python, grass-gis, pygrass

I want to export a `GeoTIFF` with `PyGRASS` but i can't figure out how I can do that.
my code so far:

```
# import grass python libraries
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import vector as v
from grass_session import Session

inputfile = './data/gtifs/13.tif'

with Session(gisdb="./tmp", location="location", create_opts="EPSG:4326"):
    r.external(input=inputfile, output="layer_1", overwrite = True)
    print(r.info(map="layer_1").get_dict())

    r.mapcalc(expression='if(layer_1>0, 1, null())',overwrite=True)

    print(g.list(type='raster', flags="m").get_dict())
    # neither of the approaches below work
    r.external.out(directory='./', format="GTiff")
    r.out.gdal(input='layer_1', output='./test.tif')
```

`r.out.gdal()` produces an `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r.out': 'r.out'` and an `GrassError: Error running: 'r.out --interface-description'.` error

`r.external.out()` does not seem to exist as a method

how do I save my grass raster as an `GeoTIFF`? I'm using the Grass GIS 7.8 binaries and python 3.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the "Modules" approach of PyGRASS, be sure to change the second dot in 3-word-commands to an underscore:

No:

```
r.external.out(...)
r.out.gdal(...)
```

Yes:

```
r.external_out(...)
r.out_gdal(...)
```

See "Example 3, using "shortcuts" and external raster format support" in
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#pygrass_Library